# How can I keep track of user specifically? Example, via using their permanent private IP

Tags: php, networking

Today I decided I want to work more on my framework and want to add rate limiting.  I have done such a thing before and had it working.  It worked by getting your public router mask IP and storing it in a database, then on every request it counts it, and once reached to a limit, it will start blocking you for some time then reset.

### The Problem

Well the problem is I was getting the user IP with this code snippet:

```php
$client['IP'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

This code gets the public IP of the client or the MASKED IP that your router assigns.  Now this is a problem because if one person on the network is spamming and is the bad guy, the good guy on the network will also be rate limited cause after a certain amount of rate limiting you, it blocks you for a while.

So, in PHP, is there some possible way to keep track of a pin pointed user, so I can have something that will guaranty to pin point the user for at least a week since you ISP keeps changing your IP every 14 days.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean anonymous users?

Comment: Not using IP alone you can't, no. Even if you could get the private IP (which you can't) it might not be unique and it's very unlikely to be permanent, and many people use more than once device anyway. Does your API employ API keys or stronger authentication?

Comment: Im not realy sure

Comment: You're developing a framework but you don't know whether you've implemented any authentication?? Are you the only developer or is it a bigger project?

Comment: its a bigger project, well for a bigger project, we plan to use this framework on other things too and where going to make it open source soon, I dont have many members just 3 of us.

Comment: I have authentication I just didn't understand your question

Comment: And yes we kinda have API keys, Im guessing its csrf type stuff to make sure the request was made by a legit user

Comment: Well it was a pretty straightforward yes/no question I thought, sorry if it was confusing somehow. Anyway my point was that the obvious way to track users is via authentication. If you allow anonymous access to some or all of the data, then you can track the user a bit using API keys, which are unique to each application or user which registers with the API, but not quite as secret. Then you can apply limits per key and/or per user. That's how big API providers such as Google do it (or, at least, one technique that they use to help with it, anyway).

Comment: API key is different than CSRF. CSRF is used on UI forms to prevent non-UI users from submitting. API key would be used when you have things like JSON endpoints intended for machine-to-machine communication rather than human interaction through a browser where no login is required in order to access the data (because it wouldn't be possible to issue a CSRF token or require an authentication token in that scenario).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using IP alone you can't, no.

Even if you could get the private IP (which you can't)...

- it probably won't be unique (except within that private network),
- it is very unlikely to be permanent (largely because of DHCP),
- the same device can switch networks (e.g. different Wifi networks, or 4G) giving it a different public and private IP each time, and
- many people use more than one device anyway.

One obvious and more reliable way to track users is via your authentication scheme. If users must authenticate before sending requests to your endpoints, you can track the number of requests made by a specific user and put limits on that. (If you want to be subtle you can impose different limits for different endpoints depending on their sensitivity or popularity, or the load they cause on your infrastructure. You could also potentially limit a user per IP, if they connect from more than one IP, and you think it make sense.)

If you allow anonymous access to some or all of the data, then you can track the user a bit using API keys, which you would issue as a GUID to each application or user which registers with the API, but they are not quite as secret. You can then apply rate limits per key and/or per user. That's how big API providers such as Google do it - or, at least it's one technique that they use to help with rate limiting (and other things), anyway.